# How I can update,save and display avatar in Vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I need to make update form,that upade,save in database and display it.
But when I submit it, avatar is updated  and saved in database, but is not displayed on screen.

In console I get  ***GET http:// test.test/storage/user/87RJoURXCX6o0ZcK.jpeg 404 (Not Found)*** error

This is template in my Vue commponent:

```
<template>
<div class="settings__card mt-64 mb-64">
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
            <default-field :error="errors.get('avatar')">
                <template #label>
                    <v-label>{{ $t("settings.user.avatar") }}</v-label>
                    <div class="form__avatar">
                        <img
                            :src="avatar"
                            onerror="javascript:this.src='/imgs/icons/avatar_inactive.svg'"
                            alt=""
                        />

                </template>
                <template #field>
                    <v-input
                        id="file"
                        type="file"
                        accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"
                        classes="form_file"
                        :error="errors.get('avatar')"
                        @change="handleAvatarChange"
                    />
                </template>
            </default-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-64 settings__card__button">
            <v-button
                type="submit"
                classes="button button-outline-accent button-lg"
            >
                {{ $t("settings.user.button") }}
            </v-button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is script in my Vue Component:

```
<script>
    import Errors from "../../../../../helpers/Errors";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                form: {
                    avatar: "",
                },
                avatar: "",
                busy: false,
                errors: new Errors(),
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.setData();
        },
        methods: {
            async submit() {
                const form = new FormData();
                form.append("avatar", this.form.avatar);
                form.append("_method", "put");
                try {
                    const {data} = await axios.post("/api/user/settings", form);
                    this.$root.user.avatar = data.data.avatar;
                } catch (errors) {
                    if (errors.response.status === 422) {
                        this.errors.record(errors.response.data.errors);
                        return;
                    }

                    this.$toastr.e(this.$t("toastr.errorMessage"), this.$t("toastr.error"));
                }
            },
            async handleAvatarChange(event) {
                this.errors.clear("avatar");
                this.form.avatar = event.target.files[0];
                this.avatar = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.form.avatar);
            },
            setData() {
                this.avatar = this.$root.user.avatar;
            }
        },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: it is uploaded in storage

Comment: this is route in api.php
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
        Route::name('user.')->prefix('user')->group(function () {
            Route::prefix('settings')->group(function () {
                Route::put('/', [SettingsController::class, 'update'])->name('settings');
            });
)};
)};

and this is route in web.php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/settings', SettingsController::class)->name('settings');
});

Comment: Comments are limited, so I send routes that include settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221453/discussion-between-tttttpr-and-kamlesh-paul).

Comment: u can add in question

Comment: do you have the symlink?  php artisan storage:link